# CSS style doesn't apply when javascript code is executed

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm catching a GET request from another page with PHP and displaying all the info to the user with something that looks like this (Using bootstrap):

[image]

But I'm getting this:

[image]
I'm using the alternative syntax for control structures and works fine. But the CSS is not applied and I don't know why. This is the relevant code:

```
        <?php

        $transactionId = $_REQUEST['transactionId'];

        if ($_REQUEST['transactionState'] == 4 ):
            $estadoTx = "Transacción aprobada";
            ?>        

            <div class="container-fluid"> 
                        <ul>
                            <li class="row">
                                <span class="itemName" id="quantity_first_product">Estado de la transaccion: </span>
                                <p class="description"><span  id="state"></span></p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="row">
                                <span class="itemName" id="quantity_first_product">ID de la transaccion: </span>
                                <p class="description"><span  id="transactionID" ></span></p>       
                            </li>                            
                        </ul>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var transaction_state;
                var transactionState_span = document.getElementById("state");
                transaction_state = <?php echo json_encode($estadoTx); ?>;
                transactionState_span.innerHTML = transaction_state;

                var transaction_id;
                var transactionID_span = document.getElementById("transactionID");
                transaction_id = <?php echo json_encode($transactionId); ?>;
                transactionID_span.innerHTML = transaction_id;
            </script>

         <?php else:
            $estadoTx=$_REQUEST['mensaje'];
            ?>
            <h1>Determinar que sucede</h1>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

The two CSS styles are:

```
.itemName{  
    color: #727578;
    font-size :16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    padding-left:25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.description{   
    color: #4ea6bc;
    font-size :18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float : left;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

When the code is executed by the browser, the PHP code inside the javascript lines works fine:

[image]

I'm doing my best but nothing works. Sorry for the long post and thanks for any help!

### EDIT

The CSS is imported in the head section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/custom.css"/>
```

and sorry for the duplicated IDs, some ctrl-c ctrl-v issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you're doing. The fact that I don't speak Spanish doesn't help either, but I'll try my best.

- **You left out the most important information: How do you import the CSS?**
- Regardless ot that, the first thing to note is this: Do **not** use the same id twice.
  `<span class="itemName" id="quantity_first_product">` should be `<span class="itemName" id="somedifferentid">`.
- Next thing is, when I tried to run this, the CSS worked, but I got complete gibberish. It looked like this:
  [image: Gibberish]
- So I added a few rules to make it look better:

  ```
  li.row {
      clear: both;
      list-style-type: none;
  }
  ```

  And that margin on the description doesn't look good at all, so I removed that too:

  ```
  .description {
      [...]        
      margin:0px;
  }
  ```

  Now it looked like this:

  [image]
- So the CSS cleary works on my end. Here's a working example:

  **Source of the get-data:**

  ```
  <form method="get" action = "newEmptyPHP.php">
      <input name = "transactionId" type="hidden" value="some-weird-id" >
      <input name = "transactionState" value="4">
      <textarea name = "mensaje"  rows="1" cols="50">Not everyone speaks spanish</textarea>
      <input type = "submit" value="Submit" >
  </form>
  ```

  **Your php file**:

  ```
  <?php
  $transactionId = $_REQUEST['transactionId'];
  if ($_REQUEST['transactionState'] == 4):
      $estadoTx = "Transacción aprobada"; ?>        
      <style>
          li.row {
              clear: both;
              list-style-type: none;
          }
          .itemName{  
              color: #727578;
              font-size :16px;
              font-weight: bold;
              float: left;
              padding-left:25px;
              margin-right: 25px;
          }

          .description{   
              color: #4ea6bc;
              font-size :18px;
              font-weight: bold;
              float : left;
              padding-left: 15px;

              margin: 0px;
          }
      </style>
      <div class="container-fluid"> 
          <ul>
              <li class="row">
                  <span class="itemName" id="quantity_first_product">Estado de la transaccion: </span>
                  <p class="description"><span class="description"  id="state">This description is in English, because I don't speak spanish.</span></p>
              </li>
              <li class="row">
                  <span class="itemName">ID de la transaccion: </span>
                  <p class="description"><span class="description" id="transactionID" >This description is in English, because I don't speak spanish.</span></p>        
              </li>                            
          </ul>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          var transaction_state;
          var transactionState_span = document.getElementById("state");
          transaction_state = <?php echo json_encode($estadoTx); ?>;
          transactionState_span.innerHTML = transaction_state.toString();

          var transaction_id;
          var transactionID_span = document.getElementById("transactionID");
          transaction_id = <?php echo json_encode($transactionId); ?>;
          transactionID_span.innerHTML = transaction_id.toString();
      </script>
  <?php 
      else:
          $estadoTx = $_REQUEST['mensaje']; ?>
          <h1>Determinar que sucede</h1>
          Something's missing here, compadre.
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much, compadre! Nice sense of humor :). Sorry for the latino post although your response was very useful and complete. Actually the error was mine! The CSS file in the server was outdated and didn't include the description rule lol. But I fixed other dummy errors with your answer

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)